# Symfony cache eclipse xDebug

Tags: eclipse, caching, netbeans, eclipse-luna, symfony-1.2

I have a really frustrating problem with eclipse PDT. When I am debugging I am getting exceptions all the time(which should not be there) I suspect the eclipse cached some of the files and this is the reason why I am getting those exceptions. I am sure that the code is correct at least where eclipse is throwing the exceptions since when I look at the code in NetBeans I can step over it without getting any exceptions whatsoever. There's a checkbox for symfony in NetBeans which can ignore the symfony cache and I guess that's why I am able to debug in there. However I very much like eclipse and I'd like to use it as a debuging and coding tool.

P.S.
 I have cleared the symfony cached via cmd and tried again but I had no luck.

I am open to any suggestions that'd fix my issue, thanks!

P.S.2
I am using ecliplse luna and symfony 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is too late, but I am posting the answer for any who might still struggle with this issue. The problem in my case was that in the debug view in eclipse I have had some variables that could not be resolved in the context when I was debugging (for example old variables that I have watched in other debug sessions). And when they were miscalculated eclipse's debugger had stopped responding. So if you have a similar problem my suggestion would be: *first clear all previous variables from the debug view*.